# resize image by height and keeping width by original aspect ratio

Tags: php, image

```
$ratio = 16/9;
$rat = $info[0] / $info[1];

if ($rat == $ratio){
    $newimg = imagescale($newimg, 960, 540, IMG_BICUBIC);  // this works
}

elseif ($rat > $ratio){
// here I want something like:
    $newimg = imagescale($newimg, 'auto', 540, IMG_BICUBIC);
}
```

So how to scale only height to 540 and scale width automatically, keeping the aspect ratio?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Proportional image resizing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440113/proportional-image-resizing)

Comment: There's a good answer here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6440113/proportional-image-resizing

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use `$rat * 540` to keep the same ratio, instead of `'auto'`:

```
$newimg = imagescale($newimg, $rat * 540, 540, IMG_BICUBIC);
```

So, if ratio is `4/3` by example, the width will be: `540*4/3 = 720`.
If the ratio is `16/9`, `540*16/19 = 960`.

Comment: you probably mean `540 * (4/3)` ?

Comment: @blueSky `540*4/3` is equal to `540*(4/3)`.

Comment: It cannot be the same, of course. Use your calculator to check

Comment: how it is possible? First case means `2160/3`. Second case means `540 * 1.33333...`

Comment: @blueSky It's the same: https://3v4l.org/LH3cJ (In the case, we got `719.999999` because we use an approximate value of `4/3`). But brackets are useful in case of addition/subtraction with multiplications and divisions.

Comment: @Syscall is correct. Don't argue against standard logic. I wonder sometimes if basic arithmetic is taught anymore.